# Reference for Zassenhaus bound of roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, reference-works

I remember  author of some textbook alluding to Zassenhaus and Knuth's bound of the zeros of a complex polynomial.Unfortunately after even after days of  search I could not find some reference or source for it.I would be highly obliged if somebody could provide some source

Comment: May [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange's_and_Cauchy's_bounds)? To quote Wikipedia: "Another bound, originally given by Lagrange, but attributed to Zassenhaus by Donald Knuth".